# Isomerization of tertiary carbocations in cholesterol synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

The following reaction mechanism happens in cholesterol synthesis inside human body. I am unable to understand why on earth the hydride shift happens here. I mean its already a tertiary carbocation, by this hydride shift I am again going to another tertiary carbocation. Can someone throw some clue on this? This reaction happens inside human cell, i.e. pH 7.4, and room temperature.

[image]

The picture is from McMurry's book on Chemistry.

Comment: If the above transformation was depicted in a journal article, book, web site, add this as a reference.  For the educational benefit of future readers of your question, may you add the conditions (e.g., temperature, presence of reagents, reaction time, yield or percentage of conversion) leading to said reaction.